# Free to use map for laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any map API that we can use instead of google map API that has free requests because google map API has limitations for free and able to set markers on the map. I use Laravel and Vuejs...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm using leaflet map, it's an open source map and its easy to use. There are also guides and tutorials available here https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/.

Give it a try and you might love it like I do.